# Struts (1.2.9) action mapping error: No action instance for path '/foo' could be created

Tags: struts, action, struts-config

I get this error :No action instance for path '/foopath' could be created

**WHEN**

```
-FORM-
package com.company.appname.web.forms;

public class fooForm extends ActionForm {
...

-ACTION-
package com.company.appname.web.actions

public class FooAction extends Action

public ActionForward execute(...) {

    return mapping.findForward("success");

}

**struts-config.xml**

    <form-bean
        name="fooform"
        type="com.company.appname.web.forms.fooForm"/>
    ... 
    <action
        path="/foo"
        type="com.company.appname.web.actions.FooAction"
        name="fooform"
        scope="session"
        input="/WEB-INF/foo.jsp">                        // it tried just 'foo.do' and 'foo.jsp' as well
        <forward name="success" path="/WEB-INF/foo.jsp"/> 
    </action>

**tiles-defs.xml**
    <definition name="Foo.def" extends="reporting.common">
        <put name="body" value="foo.jsp"/>
    </definition>
```

**AND**

```
https://localhost:8080/appname/foo.do
```

**THROWS**

```
HTTP Status 500 - No action instance for path /foo could be created
```

The poen is that I had another action (total similar, writen by somebody else) and it works:)

**Question**

```
How can I find out what is the real problem ? Is there any solution which shows more related this error ?
```

*comment:*

I could not do more similar action than i mentioned above, and the thruth is that the application has overcomplicated build system.
Application log level is trace and doesnt show anything interesting.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Cs

Answer (score 1):

the problem is solved.

The problem was that, two app was under project folder : *user* and *admin* section

Although the *'com.company.appname.web.actions.FooAction'* was totaly similiar to other actions e.g *'com.company.appname.web.actions.SimiliarAction'*

But the *'SimiliarAction'* was in another directory and ant build was charge fo producing final *'struts-config.xml'* according to two kind of application.

Comment: Hey I have the same problem. Would you be able to tidy up then English on this if possible? I can't understand what you're trying to say here.